# Abundant numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers

I have been trying to generate all the abundant numbers. But I am getting a blank screen as output? I am putting all the numbers that are abundant in an array and then printing the array. But it's not showing anything? Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[28123];
    int sum = 0,k=0;
    for(int i = 1;i<28123;i++){
        for(int j= 1;j<i;j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                sum = sum + j;
                //cout<<sum<<endl;
            }
        }
        if(sum == i){
            arr[k] = i;
            cout<<i<<endl;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for(int y = k;y<28123;y++){
        arr[y] = 0;
    }
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(int h= 0;h<k;h++){
        cout <<arr[h]<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? I.e., are you sure that `k` is incremented? and, like @Scott said, you should initialise `sum` to 0 every time before the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd want to re-initialize `sum` at the start of each iteration of the first/outer loop.